# How to vertically center a scaled View?

Tags: android

I'm trying to vertically center a rotated and scaled View. It doesn't seem to matter if it is rotated or not (if I keep the scale at 1.0 and rotate the view, and change the x position of the view by using setX it works as expected).

I know the center of my container, and I also know the width of the rectangle that holds the View in the container.

I am setting X of the View to be: the middle of the container - view/2.
This works if I don't scale the view up or down, however if I scale the image up the image doesn't appear in the center, it is always off a noticeable amount.

```
    // Get center of container
    val rect = Rect()
    containerView.getHitRect(rect)
    val width = rect.right - rect.left
    val centerContainerView = rect.left + width/2

    // At this point assume myView is rotated and scaled up (using any one of the many translate, scale, rotate on touch libraries)
    val viewRect = Rect()
    myView.getHitRect(viewRect)
    val viewWidth = viewRect.right - viewRect.left
    val newX = centerContainerView - viewWidth/2
    // Tap a button and run the below to center myView
    myView.x = newX.toFloat()
```

[SetX](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setX(float))

Comment: Are you using the original image size when you're using `setX(...)`? Or are you using the new scaled size

Comment: need some code you've used, so we can discuss. Sounds like setX is still acting on the original bounds rather than the scaled bounds. have you tried (setX * scaleFactor)

Comment: Added some code.. I'm using Rect to figure out the width, isn't that the width after scaling?

Comment: You've missed out the bit where/how you do the scaling :-) that's the bit of code that matters